# Modern rootstock for grape vine

Tags: grafting, grape-vine

There are a lot of classic rootstocks in use where I live, like SO4 (Selection Oppenheim 4), Chasselas x Berlandieri 41 B, Kober 5BB, but I'm interested in rootstocks in use nowadays in Europe.

What are the most used rootstocks for Cabernet Sauvignon or Muscat Ottonel, for example, in the present times, in places where the soil is average?
I'd prefer examples of rootstocks that give precocity because winters are sometimes hard and the wood needs to be prepared.

Comment: I'm feeling old. I was thinking your list were "modern".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your list are pretty modern stock. They are still produced, and they work well in average soil.  You need something "special" for very dry places.

But I warn you about precocity. Grape vines are very sensible to froze in spring, so in case of late freeze, you risk to have a very reduced harvesting (like this year).

I think you should choose an over variety of grapes.  Cabernet Sauvignon is a vine of "third period", so avoid it if you have long winter.